# Angular HTTP request follow link to another endpoint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

I am using ng-repeat to print a list of posts to the page via the WordPress REST-API. I am using Advanced Custom Fields on each post. From what I can see everything is working, but the post data is not showing in one container, yet it is displaying in another. I should also mention that this is set up like tabs. (user clicks a tab for a post and it displays that posts data)

Here is the code:

```js
   var homeApp = angular.module('homeCharacters', ['ngSanitize']);
   homeApp.controller('characters', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.myData = {
       tab: 0
     }; //set default tab
     $http.get("http://bigbluecomics.dev/wp-json/posts?type=character").then(function(response) {
       $scope.myData.data = response.data;
     });
   });
   homeApp.filter('toTrusted', ['$sce',
     function($sce) {
       return function(text) {
         return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
       };
     }
   ]);
```

```html
HTML:

<section class="characters" ng-app="homeCharacters" ng-controller="characters as myData">
  <div class="char_copy">
    <h3>Meet the Characters</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="item in myData.data" ng-bind-html="item.content | toTrusted" ng-show="myData.tab === item.menu_order">
      <!--this is the section that will not display-->
      <h3>{{ item.acf.team }}</h3>
      <h2>{{ item.acf.characters_name }} <span>[{{item.acf.real_name}}]</span></h2>
      <p class="hero_type">{{ item.acf.hero_type }}</p>
      {{ item.acf.description }}
      <a href="{{ item.acf.character_page_link }}">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="char_tabs">
    <!--if I put the identical {{}} in this section it WILL display-->
    <nav>
      <ul ng-init="myData.tab = 0" ng-model='clicked'>
        <li class="tab" ng-repeat="item in myData.data" ng-class="{'active' : item.menu_order == myData.tab}">
          <a href ng-click="myData.tab = item.menu_order">
            <img src="{{ item.featured_image.source }}" />
            <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

I should also mention that I use Ng-inspector, and it does show the data being pulled in. I can confirm this via the console. I have checked to ensure no css is in play; the div is totally empty in the DOM.

I appreciate all the help the GREAT angular community has shown!

Comment: `ng-controller="characters as myData"` this sets a new instance of your `characters` controller onto the scope's `myData` property. Inside your controller, you override this with `$scope.myData = ...`. To access `myData.tab` in the template, the controller should do `this.tab = 0`. Look up "controller as" syntax documentation for more info.

Comment: You don't need $scope injected into your controller at all to show data in the template if you are using `controller as x` just do `this.abc = 'asdf'` in the controller and `x.abc` in the template. Here is an example of proper use of this syntax: https://jsfiddle.net/gdLx2355/

Comment: Im really sorry I forgot to change the title of this question! I am really not following a new endpoint! I sorted that part out. I am not totally sure I follow your solution. I will re-post this question with the proper title.